# Show that $\lim_{x \to x_0} \chi_K(x)=0$ at all points not in the Cantor set and that this limit fails to exist at all points in the Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set

Denote $C$ as the Cantor set and denote $\chi_K$ as its characteristic function such that:

$ \chi_K(x)=\begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1 & x \in C \\
      \ 0 & x \notin C
    \end{array}
\end{array}$

Now, obviously for all $x \notin C, \chi_K(x) =0$  because $\chi_K(x) =0$ if and only if $x \notin K$, simply by definition.

For the latter statement ($\lim_{x \to x_0} \chi_K(x)=0$: this is true because each no point in the Cantor set is an interior point. In other words, $C^o=\emptyset$

Therefore, for $x \in C$, $\nexists \epsilon>0: (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subseteq C$

Any advice on how to prove this mathematically?

Comment: Cantor set has measure $0$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy True, but that's not the point, here (measure doesn't even enter the question). The complement of the Cantor set is an open set, that's the point.

Comment: @ProfessorVector $2\epsilon= m(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon) \leq m(C)=0$ is a contradiction. [$m$ denotes Lebesgue measure].